# Patch function formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, error, modern-experience, powerapp

I am testing Patch functionality on PowerApps to store records on a SharePoint list.

I created a simple dropdown and button to test functionality. I do have a formula error, that I cannot figure out?

Note: SharePoint list column has been set to text. Can any one help? Thanks a million!

```
Patch(SelfAssessments, Defaults{SelfAssessments} {AssessmentType: (Dropdown1. Selected.Value})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that there are some syntax errors in your formula:

1. Extra space in your formula after the name of your dropdown control.
2. Wrong parentheses for `Defaults` function.
3. Missing one comma after `Defaults`.
4. Extra Parenthesis before `Dropdown1. Selected.Value`.

Try using:

```
Patch(SelfAssessments, Defaults(SelfAssessments), {AssessmentType: Dropdown1.Selected.Value})
```

**Microsoft documentations**:

1. [Patch function in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-patch)
2. [Defaults function in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-defaults)

Comment: Dearest ganesh! 
You are a start! 
It did work! thank you sooo much!